# TryValidateModel in ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am writing a similar testing framework like this one: https://github.com/ivaylokenov/MyTested.WebApi but for ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 (using 6.0.0-beta8).

I have a hard time trying to invoke the controller's TryValidateModel to validate the ModelState of a given object. It worked without any pain on ASP.NET Web API 2 controller. Which properties should I instantiate on the controller class in order for the method to validate with the default conventions. I receive either null reference exception or valid model state no matter the model and the property attributes.

I've been searching in the [MVC](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) source code for a couple of hours with no luck. I have tried to set the AddMvc() services on the controller - not working for me. I even tried their testing controller type located [HERE](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/b8d58133c327fa9f96b24738a0a142b926acc4b9/test/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Test/ControllerTest.cs) (the GetController private method) but with no luck. Here is the source I am currently using:

```
        // TODO: for real this is how we configure controller?
        var detailsProviders = new IMetadataDetailsProvider[]
        {
            new DefaultBindingMetadataProvider(new ModelBindingMessageProvider
            {
                MissingBindRequiredValueAccessor = name => $"A value for the '{ name }' property was not provided.",
                MissingKeyOrValueAccessor = () => $"A value is required.",
                ValueMustNotBeNullAccessor = value => $"The value '{ value }' is invalid.",
            }),
            new DefaultValidationMetadataProvider(),
            new DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider(),
            // new DataMemberRequiredBindingMetadataProvider(), TODO: not available in version 8 but it is in the source code of MVC
        };

        var compositeDetailsProvider = new DefaultCompositeMetadataDetailsProvider(detailsProviders);

        var metadataProvider = new DefaultModelMetadataProvider(compositeDetailsProvider);
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

        var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(metadataProvider, new ModelStateDictionary());
        var tempData = new TempDataDictionary(new HttpContextAccessor(), new SessionStateTempDataProvider());

        var bindingContext = new ActionBindingContext()
        {
            ModelBinder = new GenericModelBinder(),
            ValueProvider = new CompositeValueProvider(new IValueProvider[0]),
            InputFormatters = new List<IInputFormatter>(),
            ValidatorProvider = new DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider(
                options: null,
                stringLocalizerFactory: null)
        };

        this.Controller.ActionContext = actionContext;
        this.Controller.BindingContext = bindingContext;
        this.Controller.MetadataProvider = metadataProvider;
        this.Controller.ViewData = viewData;
        this.Controller.TempData = tempData;
        this.Controller.ObjectValidator = new DefaultObjectValidator(new IExcludeTypeValidationFilter[0], metadataProvider);
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's the error? :)

Comment: I receive either null reference exception in DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider or valid model state no matter the model and the property attributes. These are the too situations I managed to get to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is actually a bug in ASP.NET MVC and the team will fix it for the next RC2 version: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3586